# Infix to prefix

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees

According to this algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

when a left parenthesis is found, it is inserted into the stack, and when a right parenthesis is found, we pop all operands up to the left parenthesis. Neither parenthesis is included in the output.

But what if I want expressions such as "function(x) + 5" or "array[x] + 5"? How would the algorithm work when '(', ')', '[', ']' are seen as operands?

Can someone show me the prefix version of, say, "a[x] + 5"?

Comment: For example, "x + 5" is "x 5 +".

Comment: The above comment, to be clear, shows an example of the infix expression "x + 5" being represented as the postfix expression "x 5 +". The corresponding prefix version would be "+ x 5"

Answer (score 1):

The operations must be made explicit as functions first.  An expression such as

```
function(x) + array[x] + 5
```

really is special syntax for something like this:

```
sum(sum(apply_function(function, x), array_element(array, x)), 5)
```

which can then be translated to postfix notation:

```
function x apply_function array x array_element sum 5 sum
```

and that is pretty much what it would look like in a language based on postfix notation, such as [PostScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript).